# Azure Storage - Get a list of blobs in a container with the v12 SDK for .NET

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to list blobs in an Azure Storage Account container using the [Azure Blob storage client library v12 for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet). However, I'm failing, and I suspect I'm just doing silly things.

I have a method in a class to get the blobs, which seems to work as expected -

```
public AsyncPageable<BlobItem> GetBlobs(BlobContainerClient container)
{
    return container.GetBlobsAsync();
}
```

When I pass those blobs to a new instance of another class I'm seeing some unexpected behaviour. In this class, I expect the `GetItems` method to populate `List<Item> Items`. However, the behaviour is intermittent, and seems to only work the first time I call the method after starting my app - after that, `List<Item> Items` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class GetBinResponseBody
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    public Bin Bin;
    public List<Item> Items;

    public GetBinResponseBody(BlobContainerClient container, AsyncPageable<BlobItem> blobs)
    {
        this.Bin = new Bin(container);
        this.GetItems(blobs);
    }

    public async void GetItems(AsyncPageable<BlobItem> blobs)
    {
        this.Items = new List<Item>();
        await foreach (BlobItem blob in blobs)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new Item(blob));
        }
    }
}
```

Just for completeness, here is the the `Item` class.

```
class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public string ContentType;

    public Item(BlobItem blob)
    {
        BlobItemProperties properties = blob.Properties;

        this.Name = blob.Name;
        this.ContentType = properties.ContentType;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some further research I came across the Factory Pattern, and using that I am now seeing `List<Item> Items` correctly populated after every call.

```
class GetBinResponseBody : ResponseBody
{
    public Bin Bin;
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

    public static GetBinResponseBody CreateAsync(BlobContainerClient container, AsyncPageable<BlobItem> blobs)
    {
        return new GetBinResponseBody().InitializeAsync(container, blobs).Result;
    }

    private async Task<GetBinResponseBody> InitializeAsync(BlobContainerClient container, AsyncPageable<BlobItem> blobs)
    {
        this.Bin = new Bin(container);
        await foreach (BlobItem blob in blobs)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new Item(blob));
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```